# laravel with phpexcel using columnIndexFromString

Tags: laravel-5, phpexcel

I am current using this

```
Excel::create('Export Test',function($excel) use($printData){
    $excel->sheet("Paper Print", function($sheet) use($printData){
        return $sheet->stringFromColumnIndex(5);
    }
}
```

the problem is it says the method doesnt exist.

I have tried `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(5);`

This says PHPExcel_Cell doesnt exist which would make since.

`$excel->stringFromColumnIndex(5)` also doesnt work because $excel doesnt exist.

From the documentation these methods should be available from both $excel and $sheet.

Comment: want to add that this is Mattwebsite Laravel package with PHPExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the \ in front of the PHPExcel_Cell class reference because  it doesn't exist in your App\Http\Controllers namespace.

```
Excel::create('Export Test',function($excel) use($printData){
    $excel->sheet("Paper Print", function($sheet) use($printData){
        return \PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(5);
    }
}
```

This ensures you are calling the Class::Method from the Global Namespace - otherwise you could add the line below to the top of your controller to use it without the \ in your anonymous function.

```
use PHPExcel_Cell;
```

Comment: perfect thank you.  could you explain why i need \.  I am still learning more about laravel.

Comment: The updated info makes it very clear.  thanks you.  understand now